# How to change input file button size?

Tags: html, css, file, input, resize

I am working with styling input file with opacity method - real input file button has opacity 0 and in front of it, using z-index is another input (with opacity: 1). Unfortunatelly I want my visible button to be squared picture (width:height: 1:1) - and unvisible input file is always rectangular (input box and select box with aspect ratio about 1:10). Question is - how to resize input file button to be squared (or any size) to make whole visible button area clickable (because only clicking invisible button causes opening browser window). Now only part of on visible button is "clickable".

CSS:

```
   <style type="text/css">
   .upload {
        position:relative;
    width:100px;
   }

   .realupload {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    opacity:0.5;
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity:0.5);
    z-index:2;
    width:100px;
   }

   form .fakeupload {
    background: url(images/bglines.png);
   }

   form .fakeupload input {
    width:0px;
   }

   </style>
```

And html:

```
<form>
   <li class="upload">
    <div class="fakeupload">
        <input type="text" name="fakeupload" style="opacity: 0;"/>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="realupload" class="realupload" onchange="this.form.fakeupload.value = this.value;" style="font-size: 5px;" />
   </li>
   </form>
```

Comment: Why are you placing a text input field on top of the file input field? That maybe your problem entirely.

Comment: changing place of input makes no difference :(

Answer (score 13):

We had a similar case.

It's not super elegant but instead of putting multiple file input you can try as following:

- increased the **font-size of the input** to increase the width of the button
- set the parent relative element **overflow:hidden**
- (optional) Set the **height to 100%**

As in the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Jtz/6/) (based on Scott's demo)

Only works on Firefox

Answer (score 1):

try using the "image" input type?

Otherwise you'll have to be sure to set the display: block parameter on the input button.

Comment: i am making upload files function with "input file" so i guess "input image" cant help me. Display: block also isn't working for me, although i might be doing something wrong. If you have any idea of solution with display: block i would appreciate some example source code.

Comment: "Image" is a way to replace the submit button, not the file input.

Answer (score 1):

To shorten input type file **button clickable area** you can try to use this:

```
form .fakeupload input {
    width:20px;
    transform: scale(0.23,1);
}
```

This will narrow the clickable area of input type file. (You can use transform: scale(x,y) - with x and y is number that will fits your need.
Remember to add proper styling for mobile devices or different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the malformed HTML is the problem. -- You can't have form tags outside of li tags.

This seems to work fine for me..... [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/a4Jtz/2/)

Comment: Yes it works but it doesnt solve the problem. Check this out:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Jtz/4/) - i want whole red area to cause click effect and start browsing files. Especially left part of 'input file' button (path input). The best idea i have for now is to make not one file input but for example 3 file inputs one below the other to make squared area clickable..

Comment: Sorry I don't see your problem here at all. The entire area reads the click.

Comment: Strange - for me only 'input file' area causes browsing effect (with transparency). Red area without transparent input file while clicking does nothing. I use firefox 10.0 - maybe that's the problem that we have different browsers?

Comment: IE 8.0 also provides only clicking on file input, not entire red area.

Comment: Indeed i found some lame solution for my problem, but it works. I created 4 input files, each with different id, one below the others. So they fill my whole div. Then I made them invisible - clicking on background of div makes open browsing window. Only one important thing was to find such a font size that both - path input and browsing button of file input have the same height.
If anybody finds better solution please share.